# WordPress Installed But Not Showing Up!

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, permissions, ftp

I successfully installed WordPress on my domain. I FTP'd and installed it manually. But, something very strange is happening. Whenever I visit my website, the default WordPress Sample Post page is not showing up. Instead the Web Host's default page is showing up.
`www.example.com` and `http://example.com` has same issue as mentioned above.
Please note that, I can successfully login to the ADMIN Dashboard. I have checked the permissions and have redone the permalinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your browser cache or use another browser to load the site, this may be a cache issue.

Comment: Yeah! Fixed It :)

Comment: if my suggestion worked, please accept it :)

Comment: Sure. Accepted! :)